# Webpacker asset pack size

Tags: webpack, webpacker

I have just deployed a change to my site but am getting this error only in production:

```
  01 WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
  01 This can impact web performance.
  01 Assets:
  01   media/images/gallery-feature-bg-cde3a3757c552a1fcd59ff149fc615dd.png (1.58 MiB)
  01   media/images/neil_photo-4e1fe99c16fe48fd2f0fd8c6213f2a4c.png (1.76 MiB)
  01   js/application-f25183b6442d6f9fb906.js (534 KiB)
  01   js/application-f25183b6442d6f9fb906.js.map.gz (524 KiB)
  01   js/application-f25183b6442d6f9fb906.js.map.br (440 KiB)
  01
  01 WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can i…
  01 Entrypoints:
  01   application (693 KiB)
  01       css/application-d8e632aa.css
  01       js/application-f25183b6442d6f9fb906.js
```

Obviously, due to the fact that I have webpacker dealing with a few images required, the size of the compiled output is going to be larger. That's fine by me. I keep seeing suggestions online with how to disable this warning but I'm unsure how to implement them as i'm using webpacker as a webpack wrapper.

I've tried adding `devtool: none` and

```
performance: 
    hints: false
```

to my webpacker.yml file but nothing appears to work. How do I disable this warning and do it in webpacker?

Answer (score 1):

For Webpacker, you can set webpack's [performance configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/performance) as follows:

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.config.merge({
  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
})

module.exports = environment
```

The config options also let you set the max size limits to be more permissive instead.

As an aside, the fact that you are getting a warning is a good indication that you could benefit from webpack's code splitting features, like [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports). In other words, a better answer to a slightly different question is simply "reduce your build size"

I wouldn't recommend disabling `devtool` to solve this problem specifically; let the decision to use sourcemaps or not and which to use be informed by build size along with debugging utility and other tradeoffs. For example, you might decide a different [sourcemap option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) may be a better size/utility tradeoff:

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.config.merge({
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map'
})

module.exports = environment
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  My concern is that if the limit for a bundle is 244Kb then how is my application meant to serve a few images which will surely break the limit of that?  It must solely be the few images I have that is causing this.  I do want sourcemaps. If i split images out into their own pack then surely they will break the size limit and then what is the solution?  Sorry, i'm just a little confused. :-)

Comment: I don't think so? The error says it's your application.js and application.css files that exceed the limit. The warning ignores your image files which are output separate from JS and CSS. Which question are you trying to ask? It would be helpful to clarify for future readers.